# Entity Framework Core built-in API vs stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to use EF Core for my database queries but being new to it I am unsure how secure the built-in methods are.

> Entity Framework Core provides a set of asynchronous extension methods that can be used as an alternative to the LINQ methods that cause a query to be executed and results returned. Examples include ToListAsync(), ToArrayAsync(), SingleAsync(), etc. There are not async versions of LINQ operators such as Where(...), OrderBy(...), etc. because these methods only build up the LINQ expression tree and do not cause the query to be executed in the database.

Due to the simplicity of the queries I am going to be doing (getting a row by looking for a username for example) I can use the inbuilt methods.

Like so

```
dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Username == username);
```

But because these values could be malicious I am unsure whether these methods would be safe as I have found no mentioning of binding the values separate to the query like would be done with PDO in PHP like what I have used before.

Thanks

Comment: If by 'Malicious' you're worrying about SQL Injection, then don't.  EF will use parameterised Queries when it crafts SQL so that won't be a problem.

Comment: @GPW I was, Thank you

Comment: no problem.  One piece of advice is be wary of doing overly complicated queries via LINQ - EF Core will sometimes decide to fetch raw results and do things in memory on the rows afterward.  Shouldn't happen except on a few weird things (like if you try to do a SUM on something which is conditional).  standard CRUD stuff is no problem, but just be a little wary if you're using EF directly for 'reporting' purposes.. It does output plenty of debug/trace info if you need to see what's going on.

Comment: @GPW note that the client-side evaluation behavior is changing in the upcoming EF Core 3.0.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-4/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ah I see.  I was first aware of this when I discovered that EF Core 2.0 didn't properly translate aggregate operations to SQL & ended up hand-crafting a lot of SQL (which in my case ended up being a good thing as performance tuning was FAR easier for my particular use case), but I'm glad that this has been changed now.  I'd rather it tell me it can't cope up front than *appear* to work in dev/testing but then choke due to volume of data in production/staging...